# Enforcing sequential order of figures and marginfigures in tufte-book

Tags: floats, tufte

Traditional figures (in the main body of the text) and margin figures are occasionally typeset in non-sequential order in tufte-book.  How can the sequential order be strictly imposed?  I've tried

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
...
\end{figure}
```

for the traditional figures, but even that doesn't always ensure the floats are typeset in sequential order.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer this question if the problem only occurs occasionally. Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in which the figures are placed out of order?

Comment: Sorry... no minimum working example.  The problem arises in complicated situations when the size of the figure and the location of the marginfigure are such that LaTeX moves the figure ahead (or behind) the marginfigure, which has different size and constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Tufte-LaTeX manual:

> The `\FloatBarrier` command will immediately process all the floats before typesetting more material. Since `\FloatBarrier` will start a new paragraph, you should place this command at the beginning or end of a paragraph.

If you use this command prior to the margin figure that's out of sequence, it will cause the earlier figures to be placed prior to typesetting the margin figure.